# Simulink for Python

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

I have been searching and found many libraries (scipy, numpy, matplotlib) for Python that lets a user easily shift from MATLAB to Python. However, I am unable to find any library that is related to the Simulink in MATLAB. I would like to know if such a library exists or something else that resembles Simulink in it's GUI and computation features.

Comment: Should this question be moved to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Hey Saad, take a look at my Quora post [here](https://qr.ae/pGjKGA).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[SimuPy](https://github.com/simupy/simupy) is a farily recent framework has similar features as simulink. There is a [SciPy 2018 presenation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4s4drO7KYnw) on it.

Comment: There seem to be more options available: [BMSpy](https://github.com/masfaraud/BMSpy), [PySim](https://pysim.org/)...

Answer (score 4):

Until now there is no library like Simulink in Python. The closest match is the Modelica language with OpenModelica and a python implementation JModelica.

Comment: Xcos in Scilab is also another (free) alternative, albeit not for Python

Comment: Also this seems interesing: PyLinX
https://github.com/PyLinX-Project/PyLinX

Comment: @Max the above link is broken, can you update, please?

Comment: Sorry, it seems as if that project does not exist any more...

Answer (score 1):

Recently I did a quick test with Xcos/Scilab following a tutorial from YT. I was very positively impressed with how good it looks and how easy and intuitive it was for me to use it, since it has been more than 20 years since I last used Simulink in University. (Note that I have never been an advanced user).
Even though the syntax of Scilab is similar to MATLAB (and like Python, quite readable and easy to understand) it even includes a translation tool to convert code from MatLab. (But I haven't tested it)

So, in summary, if all you need is a tool to simulate some engineering problem, I think you should give Scilab/Xcos a try.

Python is a great tool, but it is not the only one!

(You should always pick the "best tool for the problem", not the other way around.
And apparently, "Scilab is able to interact with any code written in Python thanks to its PIMS module." | From: https://wiki.scilab.org/Interoperability )